# Bash script help - Testing for hex value between multiple ranges

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script that will take input from dmidecode and match a specific memory address to a DIMM and my attempts so far have met with failure not worth sharing.

The output in question comes from (with sample output)

```
dmidecode -t 20

Handle 0x0036, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
        Starting Address: 0x00000000000
        Ending Address: 0x001FFFFFFFF
        Range Size: 8 GB
        Physical Device Handle: 0x001C
        Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x0035
        Partition Row Position: 1

Handle 0x0037, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
        Starting Address: 0x00200000000
        Ending Address: 0x003FFFFFFFF
        Range Size: 8 GB
        Physical Device Handle: 0x001E
        Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x0035
        Partition Row Position: 2
```

Depending on system, there could be 1 range, to several

Given a predetermined memory address, ex. 0x3fffffffe, I need to identify the range it falls in between Starting Address and Ending Address

The next step would be to show that ranges Physical Device Handle

Edit
I have continued to try and get this to work, and this was the best I could come up with so far, but its not dealing with hex values correctly

```
#!/bin/bash

dmidecode -t 20 > addrrng
grep 'Starting Address' addrrng | awk -F': ' '{ print $2 }' > startaddr

for i in cat startaddr; do
        if [ $1 -gt $i ]
           then
                grep -A3 $i addrrng
                break
        fi
done
```

Error
line 7: [: 0x003fffffffe: integer expression expected

Comment: I know you're probably frustrated with your failed attempts, but in the absence of a specific technical question, what's left is essentially just an overly-broad, open-ended "Can you do my work for me?" sort of question. That may not be your intent, but that's all you've given anyone to work with.

Comment: Having said that, I suppose a vague question deserves a vague response, so... Have you considered using `grep` and `awk` (or perhaps `sed` or `cut` in place of `awk`) to collect all the starting addresses into an array, and then do the same to get all the ending addresses into a second array? (Making sure to use `sort` as well so that each array is increasing order). Then you could implement a search algorithm that would "walk" the arrays and find the appropriate start and end addresses.

Comment: Mike, you are correct in that, that was not my intent
I was more looking for anyone who might already have done the work
However I have continued to tinker but something I'm doing is not working with hex, I think

Code added to question above

Comment: You're getting that error because `bash` doesn't know how to handle hex values. It only knows how to deal with numbers in decimal.\* So before you can compare two numbers with `-gt`, you need to convert them to decimal. An easy way I've found of doing this is using `printf` (the `bash` builtin, not the C function). For example, you can do `var=$(printf "%d" "0x100")`, which will set `var` to `256`. \* (all variables in `bash` are stored internally as plain text strings, even numbers. `bash` then converts back and forth between strings and numbers as needed, but only to/from decimal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If GNU awk avaliable:

```
dmidecode -t 20|gawk -v address=0x3fffffffe 'BEGIN{address=strtonum(address)}
               /^Handle/ {handle=$0}
               /Starting Address/ {start=strtonum($NF)}
               /Ending Address/{
                    end=strtonum($NF)
                    if ( address >= start && address <=end) {
                        print "handle: "handle;start=end=""}
                       }'
```

Will give you:

```
handle: Handle 0x0037, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
```

Comment: Thank you all for input, and thank you klashxx for the gawk script